# Excel: track number of employees at a given moment

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula

I am trying to come up with an Excel sheet where I have a set of 30-minute intervals throughout the day (starting at 10:00 and ending at 20:00) and I would like to calculate how many employees are available during each of them.

The data I have is their shift start/end and the start-end times of their lunch breaks (normally 1 hour, but for part-timers these last 30 minutes).

Here's a sample file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/op3rarsiqj1sm77/time-tracker.xlsx

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the logical AND, NOT, and IF formulas, testing for each employee and each time "IF" this time is larger (or equal) than the shift start "AND" "IF" it is smaller (or equal) than the shift stop, "AND" "NOT" within the lunch break (using a similar logic). Assuming that an employee that is arriving or leaving is still present at that time, the formula you would enter in cell G2 of the sample sheet could read

```
=AND(
     AND(IF(G$1>=$B2,TRUE(),FALSE()),
         IF(G$1<=$C2,TRUE(),FALSE())),
     NOT(AND(IF(G$1>$D2,TRUE(),FALSE()),
             IF(G$1<$E2,TRUE(),FALSE()))))
```

Copy&paste this to the other cells from G2:AA4 (for each employee and time), and you see when each employee is present ("TRUE") or not ("FALSE"). Then, you can simply add the values for each column, e.g., for column G, you could write in cell G5:

```
=SUM(G$2:G4)
```

(Again, copy&paste to the other columns for getting the results for the other times.)

**Edit:** As Dirk pointed out below, there are more concise ways of writing this as a formula. The advantage of using the lengthier version here would be to allow more customization. However, for this purpose, we'd need to put the formula above "inside out". So if, e.g., you'd want to register the employee absences with texts rather than TRUE/FALSE, e.g., "present" if present and "" if absent, you'd have to use IF as the outside function and AND and NOT inside the IF conditions, like this:

```
=IF(
     AND(AND(G$1>=$B2,G$1<=$C2),
         NOT(AND(G$1>$D2,G$1<$E2))),
    "present","")
```

The you can do the final counting by using something like

```
=COUNTIF(G$2:G4,"present")
```

Comment: @zkvvoob A COUNTIFS-formula would be better. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, good solution. In order to implement the same logic (anyone arriving or leaving is already/still at work), I'd modify your formula to `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$4,"<="&G1,$C$2:$C$4,">="&G1)-COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$4,"<"&G1,$E$2:$E$4,">"&G1)`, but this can obviously adjusted as needed.

Comment: My logic was: count as present when arriving (at the beginning of the day or after lunchbreak) and as not present after leaving (for lunch or end of day).. But off course, as you say, adjust to preference..

Comment: @urps Thank you very much for the suggestion! I've been experimenting with your formula because I wanted to add some more information (2 more 15-minute breaks which should be excluded; and accordingly to break the intervals into 15 instead of 30 minutes).

However, at some point the formula returns wrong answer - columns AH, AP and AX (marked in red).

http://www.mediafire.com/download/69dxbzcpn89yy3k/test2.xlsx

Could you have a look and help a bit more?

Comment: @urps while your formula could be skipped to `=((G$1>=$B2)*(G$1<=$C2)*((G$1<=$D2)+(G$1=>$E2)))>0` I got only 1 question: For what reason the `IF(G$1>=$B2,TRUE(),FALSE())`? this is exactly the same like just `G$1>=$B2`... or did I miss something here?

Comment: @Dirk, of course, this is a perfectly valid solution as well, I just tried to keep things readable for people less used to computer science logic as mathematical operations. Also, I had thought this would be offering a more "customizable" solution, e.g., by letting you write "absent"/"present" instead of TRUE/FALSE. But I realize that I turned the formula "inside out", the AND and NOT should be inside the IF's rather than outside. I will post the correct "customizable" solution as a separate answer.

Comment: @zkwoob: Sorry, only now I got to take a look. The value at AP seems correct - that's the second break. The other two values are related to the discussion above, on when you count people who are arriving/leaving as already/still present or not. You can adjust this by choosing  "<",">", vs. "<=", ">=". So if you consider the values at AH and AX wrong, I assume that you count people who are leaving work for the evening already gone and people just returning from their break not present yet. So you can adjust the formula switching to `J$1<$H2` (instead of "<=")  and `J$1<=$F2` (instead of "<").

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a COUNTIFS-formula.

Just put this in cell G2:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$4,"<="&G1,$C$2:$C$4,">"&G1)-COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$4,"<="&G1,$E$2:$E$4,">"&G1)
```

and fill over to AA2.