# Employee Interval scheduling formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been trying to create schedules by intervals that 1. Returns a value is the employee is working (1), another for Break (B) and another for Lunch (L). I referred to the link listed that gives a similar solution that could work, but there is still an error in the formula at Column AP. It should be returning False since the employee is at break, but is returning True. I have reversed the formula to see if that would help, but it did not:

[Excel: track number of employees at a given moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967326/excel-track-number-of-employees-at-a-given-moment/46622707?noredirect=1#comment80195989_4662)

I have tried a similar formula as shown below:

```
=IF(AND(K$3>=$C5,K$3<$F5),1,IF(AND(K$3>=$F5,K$3<$I5),"B",IF(AND(K$3>=$I5,K$3<=$D5),1,IF(AND(K$3>=$D5,K$3<=$E5),"L",IF(AND(K$3>=$E5,K$3<=$G5),1,IF(AND(K$3>=$G5,K$3<=$J5),"B",IF(AND(K$3>=$J5,K$3<=$H5),1,"")))))))
```

[image: Snip of Schedule Spreadsheet]

The only problem with this is that if I have employees working split shifts, whereby the employee only has start and stop times and a first break and then shows as break for the rest of the time the employee is at work. Any help would be appreciated! Again, I would prefer to go the route of the first option from the link that is shown above.

Comment: If you put the time in order a simple INDEX/MATCH would do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Scott...I will give that a shot and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use range names, regardless of the complexity of your formulas. I've used these:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║ Range Name  ║        Refers to         ║
╠═════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ break_1     ║ =F:F                     ║
║ break_1_end ║ =I:I                     ║
║ break_2     ║ =G:G                     ║
║ break_2_end ║ =J:J                     ║
║ emp_times   ║ =$K$3:$AU$3              ║
║ in_time     ║ =C:C                     ║
║ lunch_end   ║ =E:E                     ║
║ lunch_start ║ =D:D                     ║
║ out_time    ║ =H:H                     ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
```

Here's the formula:

```
=IF(OR(AND(emp_times>=in_time,emp_times<break_1),
       AND(emp_times>=break_1_end,emp_times<lunch_start),
       AND(emp_times>=lunch_end,emp_times<break_2),
       AND(emp_times>=break_2_end,emp_times<out_time)),1,

    IF(OR(AND(emp_times>=break_1,emp_times<break_1_end),
          AND(emp_times>=break_2,emp_times<break_2_end)),"B",

       IF(AND(emp_times>=lunch_start,emp_times<lunch_end),"L","")))
```

**Modified formula:**

```
=IF(OR(AND(emp_times>=break_1,emp_times<break_1_end),
       AND(emp_times>=break_2,emp_times<break_2_end)), "B",

    IF(AND(emp_times>=lunch_start,emp_times<lunch_end), "L",

       IF(OR(AND(emp_times>=in_time,emp_times<break_1),
             AND(emp_times>=break_1_end,emp_times<lunch_start),
             AND(emp_times>=lunch_end,emp_times<break_2),
             AND(emp_times>=break_2_end,emp_times<out_time)), 1, "")))
```

There was an inconsistency in your formula. The end times of breaks (10:15 and 15:15) are counted as 1 ("present"), whereas end time of lunch is counted as "L". If that fact was overlooked, then the above formula should work fine.

If it was intentional then you may have to change two lines of it where `lunch_end` appears, like this:

- `AND(emp_times>lunch_end,emp_times<break_2),` - line 3 of the formula
- `IF(AND(emp_times>=lunch_start,emp_times<=lunch_end),"L","")))` - last line

And your formula doesn't generate any error in column AP. Since the employee times get incremented by 15 minutes, cell AP3 should have a value of 15:45, which in the case of your example, should return a value of 1. It does.

**Another Tip:**

Whenever you have nested IFs, it's a good idea to expand the formula to multiple lines using `Alt+Enter`, and still better to indent it. It'll make it more readable and less intimidating.

Comment: Thanks! This is returning the correct data on the lines when I have a normal employee, but does not help when I have an employee who is working part time or a split shift. (i.e. Part time 8 - 12 with a 15 minute break at 10 AM, or split shift; working 8AM - 12 PM with a 15 minute break and returning at 5 PM - 9 PM with a 15 minute break.

The error in AP refers to the formulas found at "Excel: track number of employees at a given moment" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967326/excel-track-number-of-employees-at-a-given-moment/46622707?noredirect=1#comment80195989_4662

Comment: @LarrySpencer, how will the input data look for an employee working on a part time? That is, in columns E through J.

Comment: The input data would only have data in the emp_in, break 1 and emp_out columns. If I run it now, it only adds from the start of the shift to the first break. All before and after this time shows a "B".

Comment: I added the following to the beginning as well to eliminate data from any cells that do not contain a start time: =IF($C13=0,"",

Comment: @LarrySpencer, I've modified the formula to check for the breakfast and lunch times first, before checking for whether the employee is present or not. This, I think, takes care of the part-time employee. Here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/gpA8x. Let me know if that's what you want. **Note:** It works only if you also mention the break end time.

Comment: @LarrySpencer, Also, can you post a screenshot of how the input times and output would look for a person working on a split shift. That'll make it easier to understand.

Comment: @mehesh yes. The formula that you put into the spreadsheet for the part-time employee works. It will also work for the split-shift employees since each shift is entered on separate lines. All have start and stop times for the 1st break.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find out what time if the person is in or out.  Here is what I come up.

[image]

First, you will need to have a helper row (where I put in `row 4` shows `0 (in)` and `1 (out)`.  Since the data is not sorted, I have to use this formula from `cell J5` (adjust to your need) to make it work:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$5:$I$5=J3),$B$4:$I$4),I5)
```

It would be easier to use `VLOOKUP' with '1' in the 4th parameter or even`INDEX/MATCH` will work too.

But anyway, try and let me know if this is what you intended to do.